# Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/200.jpg): failed to open stream

Tags: php, mysql

In `localhost` i use `XAMPP`. What cause of this error? Help me, please.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/200.jpg): failed to open stream: Отказано в доступе in /opt/lampp/htdocs/edc/add_flat_data.php on line 14
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpDjp5FW' to 'upload/200.jpg' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/edc/add_flat_data.php on line 14

add_flat_data.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['save'])){
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $location=$_POST['location'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];



$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);            
        $image_location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

        mysql_query("insert into flats (type,location,description,image_location)
            values ('$type','$location','$description','$image_location'
            )

            ") or die(mysql_error());



    }

?>
```

Comment: check permissions to your destination directory, or might be that destination directory doesnt exist

Comment: mark@mark-Aspire-5750G:/opt/lampp/htdocs/edc$ sudo chmod 777 -R .?

Comment: juse a filename which is supported by your OS (Отказано в доступе)

Comment: or not? "edc" - my main directory

Comment: I have LINUX UBUNTU. But on my hosting this code will work?

Comment: on your upload directory `upload/` you are writing image there.

Comment: Aleksandar Vasić I don't understsnd.

Comment: YES! Aleksandar Vasić I am glad!!! This cause is permissions!!! It is work!

Comment: the problem is with the line `$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with permissions to your destination directory
add write permissions to your `upload/` directory and it will work
The script tries to create new file in `upload/` directory, and since it doesnt have write permission it cannot write file to a directory
use `chmod` to change directory permissions